# How to change serializeArray to normal object

Tags: javascript, laravel, serialization, multipleselection, serializearray

I using `serializeArray` to get all element and I am getting object like

```
[{name: "code[1][barcode]", value: "45534"},
{name: "code[1][rf_id]", value: "535353"},
{name: "code[1][serialize]", value: ""},
{name: "code[2][barcode]", value: "45534"},
{name: "code[2][rf_id]", value: "535353"},
{name: "code[2][serialize]", value: ""},
{name: "custodian[]", value: "3"},
{name: "custodian[]", value: "4"},
{name: "custodian[]", value: "5"}]
```

And I want to convert it like this

```
{
    code:[
            {barcode:"45534",rf_id:"535353",serialize:""},
            {barcode:"45534",rf_id:"535353",serialize:""}
        ],
    custodian: [3,4,5]
}
```

Currently I am using this script

```
var x = $('form#acquiredetail').serializeArray();
console.log(x);
var formData = {};
$.each(x, function(i, field){
    if(field.value.trim() != ""){
      formData[field.name] = field.value;
    }
});
```

And getting output as

Although I am able to get value of `code` properly but in backend/Laravel but the problem is with `custodian`, I am getting last value,

```
custodian[]:"5"
```

How can I fix this. Or any better solution for this ?

*My goal is to pass all element value to php with short and common code. Please suggest if any alternative of this*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the code snippet and enjoy :)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var x = 
[{name: "code[1][barcode]", value: "45534"},
{name: "code[1][rf_id]", value: "535353"},
{name: "code[1][serialize]", value: ""},
{name: "code[2][barcode]", value: "45534"},
{name: "code[2][rf_id]", value: "535353"},
{name: "code[2][serialize]", value: ""},
{name: "custodian[]", value: "3"},
{name: "custodian[]", value: "4"},
{name: "custodian[]", value: "5"}];

   var formData = {};
    $.each(x, function(i, field){
     if(field.value.trim() != ""){
      if(formData[field.name] != undefined){
       var val = formData[field.name];
       if(!Array.isArray(val)){
         arr = [val];
       }
       arr.push(field.value.trim());
       formData[field.name] = arr;
      }else{
        formData[field.name] = field.value;
      }
        }
    });
    console.log(formData );
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping,

Answer (score 2):

You will have to change your serialisation to look if an element ends with an array denoter `[]` and rebuild your keys according to the count of elements:

```js
var x = [{name: "code[1][barcode]", value: "45534"},
{name: "code[1][rf_id]", value: "535353"},
{name: "code[1][serialize]", value: ""},
{name: "code[2][barcode]", value: "45534"},
{name: "code[2][rf_id]", value: "535353"},
{name: "code[2][serialize]", value: ""},
{name: "custodian[]", value: "3"},
{name: "custodian[]", value: "4"},
{name: "custodian[]", value: "5"}];


var formData = {};
var formDataArrays = {};

$.each(x, function(i, field){
    if(field.value.trim() != ""){
      if (/\[\]$/.test(field.name)) {
        var fName = field.name.substr(0,field.name.length-2);
        if (!formDataArrays[fName]) {
          formDataArrays[fName] = [];
        }
        formData[fName+"["+formDataArrays[fName].length+"]"] = field.value;
        formDataArrays[fName].push(field.value);
      } else {
        formData[field.name] = field.value;
      }
    }
});

console.info(formData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping,